# How to cast using a passed string?

Tags: string, powershell, dynamic, types, casting

This is more of a learning exercise but I was hoping this would helpful.

I want to create a function like this:

```
function array_to_array ($stuff, $new_type){
    $new_stuff = $stuff -as $new_type
    $new_stuff 
}
```

I'm having a problem passing in strings or even a value such as `[char]` for the new_type.
I'm thinking I would need to do something like `$type = [char]` but I'm trying to keep it as string-based as possible?

Is there anyway to do this?  Such as activating a string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do:

```
[type] $new_type = "string"
```

In function, it would be:

```
function array_to_array ($stuff, [type]$new_type){
    $new_stuff = $stuff -as $new_type
    $new_stuff 
}

array_to_array 1 "string"
```

Comment: The function works exactly as desired. Thanks! It appears that [type]$new_type in the function will cast a string such as "string" or "DateTime" when called. The array methods work as well for instance "May 1, 2012", "June 1, 2013" "DateTime[]"